# Div Alignment inside a <td>

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have a `<td>` like this

```
<td valign="middle" class="table_td td top" style="width: 347px">  
<div id="Style" style="position:absolute;">
     <img src="images/additional-keywords-image.gif" style="background: middle right;">
</div> 
<span class="feature_text" style="cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="ShowPicture('Style',1)" onmouseout="ShowPicture('Style',0)" id="a1"> Featured Merchant Ad  </span><br />
<span class="feature_text_small">(Merchant Ad in Home Page,<br />  for valuable Site Exposure)</span>
```

Div id="Style" has image  bigger than the `<td>`. AIm is to show the image in div when the moveover happens on the first span. The image shows up fine. But, i want the vertical center of div picture to be at the span with id= "feature_text" and has text "Featured Merchant Ad". I have tried but could not succeed. Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Clear your question a lil bit, use class names for referencing the DIV or Span you talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i understod your question correctly, if you want to center the image in the div#style

You dont need this in img

```
style="background: middle right;"
```

Try

```
style="margin:auto;";
```

and adding this to div#style (div with id style)

```
style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<div id="Style" style="position:absolute;">
     <img src="images/additional-keywords-image.gif" style="background: middle right; position: relative; top: -20px;">
</div>
```

You are gonna have to play with the top value to get the vertical centering just right (the amount depends on the height of img).